# How to flatten an object

Tags: edit-mode

I have created a large object made up of many meshes which form a large floating dock (for flight simulator). I have determined that somehow I have got the model tilted on the X axis by adding a mesh cube at each end and noting where those cubes 'sits' next to the ends.

My problem is how can I tilt the entire model so that the base does not tilt. As part of the model is at 30 degrees to the other part I am not sure where to move the 3D cursor to so that I can 'tilt ' the entire model correctly.

[image]

Comment: We may need some clarification and a .blend file to help you out since your issue is a bit ambiguous at this point...

Comment: I tried to upload my blender file but for some strange reason it is larger than the 30Mb limit (actually 47Mb). I would like to know how to tilt an object consisting of many meshes some at 30 degrees from the others (see image). I know how to 'tilt' a single mesh but how do I 'tilt' such an object as in my image so that the entire object tilts and not just one mesh?

Comment: Is there a method to ensure all the bottom faces selected meshes are at the same 'level'/height (on the Z axis) as the X and Y axis?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the individual locations of certain pieces of your mesh, enter to edit mode by clicking the  <kbd>tab</kbd>  key. You can then select individual pieces (vertices, edges, or faces) and their coordinate information will display in the right panel. Note that faces and edges will display a median value for coordinates since they involve multiple vertices all of which are likely at different coordinates.

From there, you can select one vertex/edge/face and use the various options at **Mesh > Snap** to force the mesh to move to a specific location, or alternatively just manually adjust each piece so that it has the desired coordinates, as well as applying rotation as necessary. Using an orthographic viewport here will help make this a lot easier along with the viewport grid being displayed.